# Magneto 2 - Email has a wrong format

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I recently upgraded from 2.2.3 to 2.2.8 then to 2.3 and onto 2.3.3 and I've come across a strange error. When an order is being created, I get the following error:

> Failed address validation: Email has a wrong format

I've searched stack exchange and Magento forums and I cannot seem to find out why this is happening. In the logs, it shows a valid Paypal email address.

Any help would be appreciated.

The full error is:

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Failed address validation:
Email has a wrong format
Trace: <pre>#1 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php:447]
#2 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit() called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement/Interceptor.php:89]
#3 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->submit() called at [vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:807]
#4 Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout->place() called at [vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/PlaceOrder.php:98]
#5 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\PlaceOrder->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#9 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Express/PlaceOrder/Interceptor.php:26]
#10 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#15 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#17 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre> [] []
```

Comment: do you have access to db?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the database.

Comment: I would suggest, try to disable your custom module and theme.

Comment: I've disabled all modules and custom theme. It's still the same unfortunately. It seems to be a core issue but not seeing much relating to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can check below vendor file

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Validator.php

Here in `validate()` function there is **Email Validation** that returns this error, if email is not valid.

```
if (!filter_var($address->getEmail(), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $warnings[] = 'Email has a wrong format';
}
```

In **Magento 2.3.3** we need **PHP 7+** version. So in **PHP 7.1** some validation filter rules for email You can check that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220158/php-filter-validate-email-does-not-work-correctly?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Hope this information helpful to you!

Comment: Yes, I've found exactly where this error is generated. $address->getEmail() looks to be a valid email address but the issue remains.

Comment: Did you checked this thing in reference link ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/15LZtox6gpWr5d2ja_LYZlArFtyi2cnaK/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I did, but to be honest I didnt quite understand it.

Comment: Can you please share your email here if possible ? For which email address you're getting above issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is something related to Magento 2.3.3 bug and its now fixed on develop branch. Refer to the issues on github:

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24986
>
> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24957

And this is the pull request from develop branch:

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24906/files#diff-dfb3ee5a7f863458afea75f5524cd2e5R398

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue is with creating an order rather then sending an email. It could be related but from scanning the issues above, i dont see anything with Email has a wrong format mentioned.